# How do I assign numeric keypad shortcuts in VS2013?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, keyboard-shortcuts

In previous versions of Visual Studio (i.e. 2010) I always assigned my most frequently used shortcuts to my numeric keypad (in num lock mode). The shortcut would show up as "Num 0" (as opposed to just "0"). Now when I try to use just a numeric keypad key nothing happens. If I hold down a modifier it works. Not sure why they would impose such a limitation but I'm hoping maybe there's another setting or trick that enables a standalone numeric keypad key.